# unable to re-invoke the button after dynamic addition/deletion in angular2 +

Tags: angular, html

I have created a textbox and attached add (+) and delete (-) buttons horizontally. The first button doesn't have a delete section. Its image is -
[image: image- addnode -1]

Here, i make the add (+) button disappear after first add because of coding dependency.

Now after the required additions/deletions , i get UI as -

[image: Image 2]

**console output **

```
 inside addOne(), ngModel = 1
inside addOne , selectedAPIName = ["1"]
inside addOneMore , selectedAPIName = (2) ["1", "2"]
inside addOneMore , selectedAPIName = (3) ["1", "2", "3"]
inside addOneMore , selectedAPIName = (4) ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

However, after clicking on the delete button repeatedly, i end up like this, without any buttons to re-start or re-invoke after all deletions-

[image: Image 3]

Please help . Is there anyway to get the again start over again without page reload ?

code-
**app.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="addContainer">
  <p style="margin-left: 200px; font-size:18px">Please enter the API Object -</p>

  <table align="center">

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input *ngIf="addMore" type="text" placeholder="Enter a Node" [(ngModel)]="firstApiMining">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" style="margin-left: 10px" *ngIf="clickAgain" (click)="addOne(firstApiMining)" class="btn btn-success"> + </button>
        </td>
        <!-- <td>
          <button type="button" style="margin-left: 10px" class="btn btn-danger"> - </button>
        </td> -->
      </tr>



      <tr *ngFor="let container of containers; let i = index;" [(ngModel)]="miningname" #myElement ngDefaultControl>
        <ng-container>
          <td id="1myElement">
            <input *ngIf="addMore" type="text" placeholder="Enter a Node">
          </td>
          <td id="1myElement">
            <button type="button" style="margin-left: 10px" (click)="addOneMore(miningname)" class="btn btn-success"> + </button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" style="margin-left: 10px" (click)="deleteOneMore(i)" class="btn btn-danger"> - </button>
          </td>
        </ng-container>
      </tr>



      <tr>

        <td style="text-align:center">
          <button type="button" (click)="showGraphs()" class="btn btn-dark">Search</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
 addOne(firstApiMining){
    this.addContainer = true;
    this.addMore = true;
    this.clickAgain = false;
    this.containers.push(this.containers.length);
    console.log("inside addOne(), ngModel =", firstApiMining);
  this.selectedAPIName.push(firstApiMining);
  console.log("inside addOne , selectedAPIName =", this.selectedAPIName)
  }


  addOneMore(moreAPIName) {

      this.addContainer = true;
      this.addMore = true;
      this.containers.push(this.containers.length);
      this.selectedAPIName.push(moreAPIName);
      console.log("inside addOneMore , selectedAPIName =", this.selectedAPIName);
  }

  deleteOneMore(index){

      this.containers.splice(index, 1);
      console.log("this.index =", index)
      console.log("inside delete , api-mining-ngmodel-name = ", this.miningname);
      this.selectedAPIName.splice(index+1,1);
      console.log("inside deleteOneMore(), this.selectedAPIName =", this.selectedAPIName);
  }


  showGraphs() {
      console.log("inside showGraphs()")
      this.showEwayBill = true;
      this.showCollection = true;
       this.EwayBill();

  }
```

**Issue 2**

Please help me resolve this-

I am able to delete in the first go . But when i deleted all the previous text-boxes, I am left with this -

[image: image1]

**console output**

```
 inside deleteOneMore(), this.selectedAPIName = ["1"]
```

And clicking the add (+)button again, i get this output

[image: image 2]

**console output **

```
 inside addOne , selectedAPIName = (2) ["1", "1"]
```

here --> "1" is repeated, so the sequence of numbers is uneven and there is issue while deleting the relevant textbox value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you delete an item you need to check if their is no more items and if true enable the add button of the first item :

```
deleteOneMore(index){
    this.containers.splice(index, 1);
    if(this.containers.length == 0){
        this.clickAgain = true;
    }
    console.log("this.index =", index)
    console.log("inside delete , api-mining-ngmodel-name = ", this.miningname);
    this.selectedAPIName.splice(index+1,1);
    console.log("inside deleteOneMore(), this.selectedAPIName =", this.selectedAPIName);
}
```

Comment: please accept the answer as the correct answer to informs others that your issue is resolved

Comment: can you please help me in foolproofing the code. Because, the delete sequence when done randomly and non-sequentially after the first chance .. like on second chance when all the text-boxes are deleted and started anew, we don't get correct deletions. Like , after first deletion i get repeat value - inside addOne , selectedAPIName = (2) ["1", "1"]

Comment: i didn't understand

Comment: Hi Mustapha, I added my query in Issue 2 . Please help

Comment: and when you add two item what you get in console ?

Comment: inside addOneMore , selectedAPIName = (4) ["1", "1", "2", "3"]

Comment: if you can create a fiddle because i can't see where is the problem

Comment: Hi, I am trying to resolve my JSFiddle . I could create only this much (unable to resolve errors ) - https://jsfiddle.net/suchetacateina/1b68eLdr/83507/